# Choosing the fonts for a Windows Forms application

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to design a Windows Forms application. By default, .NET had put *Tahome 8,25* on the toolbar and Microsoft *SansSerif 8,25* on everything else. To improve the general look and feel of the forms I'd like to change them.

Which font family should I use as a default? And what size should they be?
For:

- Classic data input form (label + textbox, label + combobox...)
- Data grid

Is there a recommended way?

The application is a classic business application, you can think of it as an accounting type.

Comment: I like this comment from Microsoft on font selection:

Again, design consistency is important in choosing fonts. In most cases, you shouldn't use more than two fonts at two or three different point sizes in a single application. Too many fonts can leave your application looking like a ransom note.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733613(VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would stick with the SystemFonts as that way the app stays consistent with their main UI.  Same for colours, always tray and use SystemColor.

However if for some reason I can pick a font, before I had heard of Segoe UI, I used Verdana.

Answer (score 26):

**Segoe UI** - is a good all rounder. Introduced in Windows Vista it is used as the standard UI font, and it works well in small sizes.

[image]

Source: http://neosmart.net/gallery/v/apps/fonts/Segoe+UI.png.html

Comment: Segoe UI is just perfect to me. I am blessed for landing on your answer,

Comment: Is that font available in Windows Vista and XP ?